# Quartz composer - output specific number

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm trying to achieve something quite simple in Quartz Composer.  I'm not sure which patches to use.  I'm used to Max/MSP, and I can't find an equivalent for doing something simple: send a number out of an output with a bang or toggle. In Max you just use the a float or integer object, set the number and then send it with bang.  I cannot find a simple number patch, or the equivalent of a bang. Is there such a thing?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz Composer isn't event-based. You'll have to manage yourself the way you want to output things.

If I understand well : you want to output a number on an event (keyboard or else, I guess) and keep it until the next event.

If you already know your values, I suggest you connect to a Number Multiplexer, for example :

**keyboard -> counter -> multiplexer -> image with string -> sprite**

If you don't know them :

**keyboard -> sample & hold (sample input)

dynamic number -> sample & hold (value input) -> image with string -> sprite**

Keyboard is there to generate your 'event'. The values won't move until the next event your throw (managed by the Counter patch Increment/Decrement inputs in the first example, by the Sample input in the second).

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in replying - I had given up hope that I would receive an answer.  You have been very helpful, although I still have a lot to learn about the different way QC operates.